# Oscilloscope showing weird AC wave on DC

Tags: oscilloscope

I recently bought an oscilloscope and to test it I tried hooking it up to an Arduino.
Using the following connections:

Arduino 5V -> Scope 1 
Arduino GND -> Scope 2
The Arduino itself is powered with a USB connection to main's as well.

But this is getting shown at the scope:

[image: Oscilloscope Graph]

You can see there is a 50 Hz wave (on dc?) with almost the right voltage.
To fix this issue I tried connecting the main's ground to the earth which didn't resolve anything.

My probes are tuned correctly (using the square wave by the scope).

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: So you did not connect the probe/scope ground to Arduino ground? Also you don't even mention how the Arduino is powered, or is it powered at all? Based on your diagram, it isn't.

Comment: Assume you are somewhere where the mains frequency is 50 Hz? If so it looks like your scope probe ground is not making good contact with the signal ground.  (As @Justme is pointing out.)  Could be a bad probe, can you try another?

Comment: Show us a pic of how & where you've connected your scope probes *and their ground clips*.

Comment: Sorry yall. Connected Scope's 2 to GND not VCC

Comment: Pics, not a written description. And you still haven't told us where your scope probes ground clips are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you get that signal because that is what you are measuring - a floating USB supply in reference to scope ground.

If you want to measure between 5V and GND of the Arduino which is powered by a floating USB power supply (or if your scope is actually floating if it is not properly grounded via mains cord), the correct procedure is to connect **probe ground clip** to Arduino GND and **probe tip** to 5V.

If you do want to measure differentially with two probes, then you have to put the scope to show the result of Channel 1 minus Channel 2.

So before you damage the scope, or the Arduino, or the USB power supply, or injure yourself with an electric shock by making unsafe connections, please familiarize yourself to scopes and measuring with them before continuing unsafely or without understanding how measurements should be made and why.